# Coffeescript maven plugin gone from GitHub?

Tags: maven, coffeescript

I make extensive use of the CoffeeScript Maven Plugin which used to live here: https://github.com/iron9light/coffeescript-maven-plugin.  (if that link is no longer 404'ing then it must have come back; consider the question answered!)

It seems to have disappeared which is odd as it's always been there in the past.  I have local copy so it's not a mega problem but I would be sad if the chap who maintains it has deleted it / stopped maintaining it!

Does anyone know what happened to it?

Comment: "it's always been there in the past" -- obviously I say that within the context of a reasonable slice of the past rather than all time. I don't, for example, believe that github predates the dinosaurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, it's back now! I guess it took a little holiday. https://github.com/iron9light/coffeescript-maven-plugin